# Opengl es have Mesh class in java

Tags: android, performance, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

I am new to OpenGL ES in android. I want to learn about mesh. I only found  code in C++. But I am using java.

Does java have Mesh class? If it doesn't what should I use instead of Mesh?

Comment: Please post your work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Mesh classes you see in the c++ examples are user created therefore they are not part of core c++. The same is for Java. People create mesh classes primarily as a way to hold "mesh" related information.

If you wish to use this concept then decide what properties, for what ever objects you want to draw on screen, that you wish to group together. Examples could be, vertex data, normal data, texture data. Having all this information together then makes it easier to combine and then eventually draw objects on the screen.